# How to mock private method using Power Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, powermockito

I am trying to mock my private method , but I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class` .Below is my method

```
private String decodeResponse(byte bresp[])
    {

        String spresp = null;
        //
        return spresp;
    }
```

Below is my test class ,

```
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class MyClassTest{

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.spy(MyClass.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("abcdefg").when(MyClass.class, "decodeResponse",Matchers.anyByte());
    }   
    }
```

I am stuck in this issue for past 3 hours . Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You should avoid using Powermock (mainly because it's slow). You should make the private method protected and "abuse" this visibility in the test

Comment: You don't need to mock private method, because it's not about tdd

Comment: @fxrbfg My private method is calling from another public method

Comment: This is not a tdd way, you need to understand it. Test private methods is abuse. You need to test only public methods.

Comment: @fxrbfg Yeah , that I agree . But here in this case this particular private method is calling from another public method . And also inside this private method , my db connection does .

Comment: *"And also inside this private method , my db connection does ."* then it should not be in that class in the first place but in another class that is *injected* into your class preferably as a *constructor parameter*. Then it would easy to pass an ordinary mock faking the DB connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class MyClassTest{

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        MyClass myClassSpy = PowerMockito.spy(MyClass.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn("abcdefg").when(myClassSpy, "decodeResponse",any(byte[].class));
    }   
    }
```

Comment: MyClass have a constructor with parameters MyClass communicator=new MyClass(obj1,obj2);   Also can you please explain "any(byte[].class)" this portion .

Comment: Is it possible to mock a private method ?

Comment: since your method accepts byte array, you cannt use Matchers.anyByte(). `Matchers.anyByte()` this means any single byte not byte array

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it possible to mock a private method". Of course its possible. That is what the above code does

Comment: Ok thankyou Kiran , but have some syntax error at this area .any(byte[].class)

Comment: your method decodeResponse takes a byte array right? then that should work . You can also try Matchers.<byte[]>any() or